# The type or namespace name could not be found Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on script for my fps game, but i'm still getting this error "The type or namespace name 'Target' could not be found." I know that there's something wrong with this line of code `ReactiveTarget target = hitObject.GetComponent<Target>();` but i have no idea what it can't find this Target class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour{
private Camera _camera;

void Start(){
    _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

void OnGUI()
{
    int size = 12;
    float posX = _camera.pixelWidth / 2 - size / 4;
    float posY = _camera.pixelHeight / 2 - size / 2;
    GUI.Label(new Rect(posX, posY, size, size), "*");
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {

        Vector3 point = new Vector3(_camera.pixelWidth / 2, _camera.pixelHeight / 2, 0);

        Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(point);

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;

            ReactiveTarget target = hitObject.GetComponent<Target>();

            if (target != null)
            {
                target.ReactToHit();
            }
         
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine(SphereIndicator(hit.point));
            }
        }
    }
}
private IEnumerator SphereIndicator(Vector3 pos)
{
    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    sphere.transform.position = pos;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Destroy(sphere);
}}
```

And here's the Target script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void ReactToHit()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Die());
    }
    private IEnumerator Die()
    {
        this.transform.Rotate(-75, 0, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. This question seems to be missing some relevant information. I can only guess there's another error happening which is preventing Unity from compiling your code. And I can only guess it's from trying to assign a `Target` to a `ReactiveTarget` (a type which does not seem to exist) with `ReactiveTarget target = hitObject.GetComponent<Target>();`.  Does changing it to `Target target = hitObject.GetComponent<Target>();` fix the problem?  Either way, please edit the question to include all errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hi

There is something wrong here(Or at least this is what I think)

### How did you use the data type **ReactiveTarget** To get the data type of **Target** ?

*This is the first time I see something like this!*

Try to change

```
ReactiveTarget target = hitObject.GetComponent<Target>();
```

To:

```
Target target = hitObject.GetComponent<Target>();
```

Comment: Omg that's so obvious! I can't believe I haven't seen it, thank you!